# Access database from jar

Tags: java, jar

Im developing a little application which uses a Sqlite database.

The database file is under src/main/resources/sample.db

The problem is when i make a jar and try to run it it says the path does not exists

Comment: What JDBC URL are you using?

Comment: spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/sample.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Comment: Try `jdbc:sqlite::resource:sample.db`. Note the database is read-only when contained inside a JAR file.

Comment: isn't working either

Comment: Thank you so much mate! jdbc:sqlite::resource:sample.db. very very appreciated. Can you tell me what ::resource does?

Comment: Just an indication to the driver that the following path is relative to the root of the classpath.